Why does centering work in AMS article but not plain article?
I have a command for images. It also centres them. I mostly just used it in amsart but today I tried using it in article and the centering that previously worked in the AMS article no longer works. Here is a minimal example,
\documentclass{article}%\documentclass{amsart}
\author{Musa Al`Khwarizmi}
\date{\today}
\title{Minimal Complete Document}

\usepackage{graphicx, pgffor, ifthen}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand\img{d<>O{0.4}mm} {%
  \begin{figure}[hbtp]%
    \foreach \path [count=\i] in {#4} {%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\i}{1}}{}{\hspace{0.25cm}}%
        \begin{minipage}{#2\textwidth}%
          \centering% don't introduce new lines in \subfloat{...}
          \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\path}}%
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    \caption{#3}\IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}}%
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document} \maketitle
\img{Example Images}{example-image-a, example-image-b}
\end{document}

Could someone explain this behaviour and how might one achieve the same results despite the class used.

texdoc amsart gives that:

All AMS classes center the content of table and figure environments. Using \centering or \begin{center} and \end{center}, therefore, is unnecessary.

This can be seen from the source code in amsart.cls:
%line 1385 v2.20.6
\def\@floatboxreset{\global\@minipagefalse \centering}

But standard classes like article does not center the content of table and figure by default. So you have to issue \centering after \begin{figure}[hbtp] manually.

So right before the foreach line then?

that’s right @scribe
